# Can we have different results for the same exemple using chi 2 and KS?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, chi-squared-test, goodness-of-fit, kolmogorov-smirnov-test

I just wanted to know, can we have different results for the same inputs, using Chi 2 and KS?
So for example I suppose that my variable flows a uniform law, as I do the test, the results I have are: the hypothesis is rejected (using Chi2) and accepted (using KS)

KS means Kolmogorov-Smirnov

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you use two different tests (that are not equivalent) they will measure their relative discrepancy from the null differently -- they are sensitive to different things. In short, they "see the data differently". Consequently, some samples will be considerably further into the tail of the null distribution of one statistic than another.

As an example, a chi-squared test will tend to be less sensitive to some 'smooth' deviations from the uniformity under the null than a Kolmogorov-Smirnov might be, but relatively more sensitive to other kinds of deviations.